# Translate slug in WPMU with PO files

Tags: plugin-development, custom-taxonomy, taxonomy, translation

I created my own plugin to make some taxonomies. Now I wish translate the url, but my attemp doesnt works.

**The code of the plugin made for create taxonomies:**

```
// Crea Post Type: Settori
add_action('init', 'crea_settori');

function crea_settori() {

    $labels = array(
        'name' => __('Settori'),
        'singular_name' => __('Settore'),
        'add_new' => __('Aggiungi settore'),
        'add_new_item' => __('Nuovo Settore'),
        'edit_item' => __('Modifica Settore'),
        'new_item' => __('Nuovo Settore'),
        'all_items' => __('Elenco Settori'),
        'view_item' => __('Visualizza Settori'),
        'search_items' => __('Cerca Settori'),
        'not_found' => __('Settore non trovato'),
        'not_found_in_trash' => __('Settore non trovato nel cestino'),
    );

    $args = array(
        'labels' => $labels,
        'public' => true,
        'rewrite' => array('slug' => _('slug_funzioni', 'xxxx-theme')),
        'has_archive' => true,
        'hierarchical' => false,
        'menu_position' => 5,
        'supports' => array(
            'title',
            'editor',
            'thumbnail',
            'custom-fields'
        ),
    );

    register_post_type('settore', $args);
}
```

**In the PO files:** (Encoded into MO)

*Italian:*

```
# funzioni-per-la-xxx
msgid "slug_funzioni"
msgstr "funzioni-per-la-xxx"
```

*English:*

```
# funzioni-per-la-xxx
msgid "slug_funzioni"
msgstr "functions-for-xxx"
```

Finally I used this link in the WP theme:

```
<a href="<?php echo site_url(); ?>/<?php _e('slug_funzioni', 'xxxx-theme'); ?>/<?php _e('slug_page', 'xxxx-theme'); ?>"><?php _e('slug_page', 'xxxx-theme'); ?></a>
```

**So:**

http://it.example.com/funzioni-per-la-xxx/slug_page **Works**

http://en.example.com/functions-for-xxx/safe-and-care **Doesnt work**

Comment: your use of translation function is wrong. you always should have a text domain. Now to the issue itself, what is en.example.com and what llanguage is defined for it?